# How we can write customised Message Receiver class in Web Service using Axis2?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I need to write the customized message receiver class instead of using the `RPCMessageReceiver` which in in-out. I tried doing this but it's not working. I'm new to the web services and axis2. Can anyone help me out from this.

```
package com.webservice;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMNamespace;
import org.apache.axiom.om.util.AXIOMUtil;
import org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import org.apache.axis2.AxisFault;
import org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext;
import org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation;
import org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver;
import org.apache.axis2.util.JavaUtils;

import request.Address;
import request.TestRequest;
import response.TestResponse;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.StaxDriver;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MyServiceMessageReceiver extends AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver{
@Override
public void invokeBusinessLogic(MessageContext inMessageContext,     MessageContext outMessageContext)
        throws AxisFault {
    Object obj = getTheImplementationObject(inMessageContext) ;
    MyService webServiceImpl = (MyService) obj ;
    AxisOperation operation = inMessageContext.getOperationContext().getAxisOperation();
if (operation == null && operation.getName() != null) {
        throw new AxisFault("Operation is not located. SOAP ACTION must be specified") ;
    }
    String methodName = JavaUtils.xmlNameToJava(operation.getName().getLocalPart() ) ;
    if (methodName == null) {
        throw new AxisFault("Method with given name is not found") ;
    }

    if ("getEmployeeDetails".equalsIgnoreCase(methodName)) {
        SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = inMessageContext.getEnvelope();
        OMElement processTransactionElem  = soapEnvelope.getBody().getFirstElement();
        TestResponse testResponses = fromOM (webServiceImpl, processTransactionElem , getEnvelopeNamespaces(soapEnvelope));
        if (testResponses != null) {
            OMElement outelem = null ;
            try {
                 outelem = convertToOM (testResponses);
            } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       inMessageContext.getEnvelope().getBody().setFirstChild(outelem) ;
    outMessageContext.setEnvelope(inMessageContext.getEnvelope()) ;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Implemented");
    }
}
 private OMElement convertToOM(TestResponse testResponse) throws XMLStreamException {
        XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
        xstream.alias("testResponse",TestResponse.class);
        String xmlStr = xstream.toXML(testResponse);
        OMElement omele = AXIOMUtil.stringToOM(xmlStr);
        return omele;
}

private TestResponse fromOM(MyService webServiceImpl, OMElement processTransactionElem, Map envelopeNamespaces) {
    TestResponse testResponses = null;
     try {
         Iterator<OMElement> childElemIterator = processTransactionElem.getChildElements();
         while (childElemIterator.hasNext()) {
             OMElement childElem = childElemIterator.next();
             String childName = childElem.getLocalName();
             XStream stream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
             /*if("empId".equalsIgnoreCase(childName)){
                 empId = childElem.getText();
             }*/
             if ("getEmployeeDetails".equalsIgnoreCase(childName)) {
                 stream.alias("getEmployeeDetails", TestRequest.class);
                 stream.addImplicitArray(TestRequest.class, "address");
                 stream.alias("address", Address.class);
                 TestRequest request = (TestRequest)stream.fromXML(childName.toString());
                 testResponses = webServiceImpl.getEmployeeDetails(request);
             }
         return testResponses ;
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace() ;
     }
     return null ;
}

private Map getEnvelopeNamespaces(SOAPEnvelope env){
        Map returnMap = new HashMap();
        OMNamespace ns;
        for(Iterator namespaceIterator = env.getAllDeclaredNamespaces(); namespaceIterator.hasNext(); returnMap.put(ns.getPrefix(), ns.getNamespaceURI()))
            ns = (OMNamespace)namespaceIterator.next();

        return returnMap;
    }
```

}

When I'm trying to send the request and receive the response through SOAP UI, it's throwing response with fault code as soapenv:Receiver. Which means server is not processing the message.

Comment: So what have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: @mmmmmpie: I have edited my question with my approach. Hope it will help you in understanding my problem